# How do I get swift binary for Google Places without CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, carthage

I'm using Carthage and would like to manually install GooglePlaces. I cannot seem to find a Swift build anywhere or a way to build the swift binary for 4.2. The [manual binary framework](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/start) on Google's docs is for Obj-c.

Comment: https://github.com/leoneparise/GooglePlaces-Carthage ? You can see how the author did it or use it directly.

Comment: Thanks I found some details in a fork from there that helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827791

Google denying support for now.

Repo with directions for updating to latest. Places needs Maps it looks like.

https://github.com/kgnadinger/GooglePlaces-Carthage
https://github.com/joselinoneto/GoogleMaps-Carthage